# Replacing red wine by vinegar to do a beef salami

Tags: food-safety, substitutions, curing, salami

is it safe to replace wine by vinegar, rice vinegar or apple cider to do a homemade Salami?

Comment: Why do you want/need to replace the wine?

Comment: We are not allowed to drink alcohol in my religion and I love Salami .

Answer (score 6):

Not all salami recipes call for wine. I would advise finding one that doesn't include wine, rather than trying to adapt one that does: modifications to cured meat recipes are risky and potentially unsafe. Although replacing wine with vinegar sounds *intuitively* safe (in that it lowers the pH), it might have the effect of messing up the initial bacterial culture you're looking for.

If you can find non-alcoholic wine (assuming the alcohol is what you're worried about), it should be fine to substitute that in. The alcohol level is quite low in the mixture as a whole, and doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: I agree, vinegar is not a substitute for wine. The flavor is different, the composition is different.